# How can I simply increase the elements of the pandas series as much as I want?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to increase the number of rows in the pandas series as many as I want.

It would not be difficult if it made it very inefficient.

Example)

```
a = pd.Series([3,4,5])
b = pd.Series([1,2,3])
```

Using a and b, I want the following result.

```
pd.Series([3,4,4,5,5,5])
```

The number is b, value is a.

If I use pandas, I can increase the number by using two series like that.
If you know how to solve this problem, please teach that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with `Series` constructor, only necessary same length of both `Series`:

```
c = pd.Series(np.repeat(a.values, b))
#pandas 0.24+
#c = pd.Series(np.repeat(a.to_numpy(), b))
print (c)
0    3
1    4
2    4
3    5
4    5
5    5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Good! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can also do:

```
a.loc[a.index.repeat(b)]
#for reseting index :-> a.loc[a.index.repeat(b)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
0    3
1    4
1    4
2    5
2    5
2    5
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the best answer though:

```
>>> pd.Series([i for x,y in zip(a,b) for i in [x]*y])
0    3
1    4
2    4
3    5
4    5
5    5
dtype: int64
>>>
```